# Change Image based on screen size

Tags: html, css

First and foremost, I searched this site and others for an answer.  Only found stuff relating to iphones and androids.

So with that, I know how to change image sizes with changing screen resolutions with the `@media tags`, just not how to change the image all together (from `image1.png` to `image2.png`) with changing screen sizes.

I read the following article regarding dynamic webpages and they seem to have what I am looking for, but I don't believe they described how to change images:
http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Can this be done with basic `HTML/CSS`?

My example: When changing screen resolution from `1260px` to `480px`, change image from `image1.png` to `image2.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an image you could just use a `div` and change its `background-image` property using `media` queries. Or just show/hide (using `display: none/block`) images based on media queries.

Its not possible to change image sources without using javascript.

Comment: Using the images as backgrounds also allows to load only the required image (if the media queries are set properly), thus improving bandwidth performance
**PS:** What the OP is asking for is being prepared by the W3C. Check out the [picture](http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element) tag.

Comment: not too good with javascript. ill try your method when i get a chance